# Como crio link externo usando cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, link

Um link do tipo abaixo serve para linkar para uma página(view) de nosso próprio sistema:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Listar todas as tarefas', array('action'=>'index')); ?>
```

E se eu quiser linkar para o youtube por exemplo ou outro site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta substituir o `array` do segundo parâmetro pela URL desejada. Assim:

```
echo $this->Html->link('YouTube', 'http://www.youtube.com');
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso e e não deu certo.

Comment: Eu estava fazendo algo errado. Agora foi. Valeu.